# Test warnings for optional packages

Tags: python, unit-testing, tox

My code provides optional functionalities that use optional packages.

When a user imports a package which contains these optional features, a warning is displayed if he/she does not have the additional package installed. E.g.:

> Please install `optional-package` to use all features

In order to test these optional features, the optional package is installed as a dependency in the virtualenv that `tox` creates:

```
# tox.ini
[my-env]
deps = optional-package
```

The problem is that I want to test that:

1. A warning is displayed when the user does not have the package installed
2. The warning is *not* displayed when the user does have the package

However, it seems that python does not provide a way to unload packages.

How can I create a test to describe the context in which the user does not have the optional package on his system, if at the same time I need `tox` to automatically install it as a dependency?

Comment: You can set `sys.modules["optional.package"] = None` to force subsequent imports of the module to fail, and use `imp.reload()` to reimport the module that is supposed to warn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to test that `some_module` throws a warning when `optional.package` is not available:

```
import some_module

# ...

    @mock.patch.dict("sys.modules", {"optional.package": None})
    def test_warning_optional_package_not_installed(self):
        with self.assertWarns(SomeWarning):
            imp.reload(some_module)
```

Alternatively, you can define multiple testing environments in your `tox.ini` file, with and without the optional packages.  You can configure tox to set environment variables depending on whether the package has been installed:

```
[tox]
envlist = {with,without}_optional

[testenv]
basepython = python3.5
deps =
    required-package
    with_optional: optional-package
setenv = 
    with_optional: OPTIONAL_PACKAGE_AVAILABLE = true
commands = python -m unittest tests
```

You can then enable and disable tests based on the value of the environment variable:

```
@unittest.skipUnless(os.env["OPTIONAL_PACKAGE_AVAILABLE"] == "true")
def test_no_warning_optional_package(self):
    with warnings.catch_warnings(record=True) as w:
        imp.reload(some_module)
    self.assertFalse(w)
```

Comment: Suppose I create another `tox` environment that does not use my optional package. How can I know whether my tests are succeeding in one env or in the other? I want to make sure that the warning is only displayed when I am using the environment without the optional package, and that it is not displayed in the other environment. If I use a `try/catch` to catch an `ImportError` exception I will simply see the test succeeding in both cases, but this won't tell me which of the two behaviours is being tested. Am I right?

Comment: When using different tox environments, you would have to make your test detect what environment they are in and enable and disable tests accordingly.  The details of how to do this depend on what test runner and unit test environment you use (py.test, nose, unittest2 etc).